# WCF service and database

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service that work with databse. The service should handle incoming message and store messagId into database. Please suggest me how can I improve it?

```
public class DBWorker
{
    static DBWorker instance;
    private string connectionString;
    private SqlConnection connection;

    protected DBWorker()
    {
        connectionString = GetConncetionString();
        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
    }

    public static DBWorker Instance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new DBWorker();                
        return instance;
    }

    private string GetConncetionString()
    {
        var conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FsConnectionString"];
        if (conn == null | string.IsNullOrEmpty(conn.ConnectionString))
          throw new Exception("Couln't find connection string in app.config.");
        return conn.ConnectionString;
    }

    public void StoreMessage(string messageId)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into test (MessageId) values (@MessageId)", connection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MessageId", messageId);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

}
```

My WCF:

```
public class HostTest : IHostTest
{
    private DBWorker dbWorker;

    public HostTest()
    {
        dbWorker = DBWorker.Instance();
    }

    public Stream HandleIncomingMessage()
    {            
        var currentContext = WebOperationContext.Current;
        var request = currentContext.IncomingRequest;
        var response = currentContext.OutgoingResponse;

        string messageId = request.Headers["X-Message-Id"];

        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        response.ContentType = "text/plain";

        if (request.ContentLength == 0 )
        {
            response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                dbWorker.StoreMessage(messageId);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            }
        }

        return new MemoryStream(UTF8Encoding.Default.GetBytes(messageId)); ;
    }
}
```

Comment: You know this code doesn't compile? `conn == null | string.IsNullOrEmpty(conn.ConnectionString)` doesn't work.

Comment: @TopinFrassi No, everything compile and works fine

Comment: Hmm, your right! I didn't know you could do this. Sorry! :)

Comment: @TopinFrassi No problem =).What do you think about the naming of class, methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep your `SqlConnection` opened for the *whole application lifecycle* which is waayyy too long. BCdotWEB already covered the `using` part, which you should apply! :)

You should **never** throw `Exception`. That's mean. There is a `ConfigurationException` that exists for a good reason! When you want to throw an exception that's not related to your business logic, assume the framework already has an exception for this.

Your `DbWorker` might have concurrency issues. That's your call, but if you have a little load, it would be possible for two clients to initialize your singleton at the same time. To deal with that, you need to make the Singleton initialization thread-safe. We'll use the `Lazy<>` class.

```
public class DBWorker
{
    private static Lazy<DBWorker> instance = new Lazy<DBWorker>(() => new DbWorker(), LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);

    protected DBWorker()
    {
        connectionString = GetConncetionString();
        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
    }

    public static DBWorker Instance()
    {
         return instance.Value;
    }
}
```

The `Lazy<>` class will be executed once, in a thread-safe manner. And it'll then return the `Value` defined in the expression. If you use C#6, your `Instance` method could be a one-liner this way :

```
public static DBWorker Instance() => return instance.Value;
```

Here : `if (conn == null | string.IsNullOrEmpty(conn.ConnectionString))`

At first, I didn't think you could do this, but eh, you can! But I read on this, and there's a difference to consider between `|` and `||` operator. [Read it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550966/bitwise-or-and-logical-or-operators-whats-the-difference). Basically, using the `||` operator, if the first condition is true it won't compute the second condition, which is more performant. Using the `|` operator, each conditions are evaluated, and *then* we'll verify if it's `true` or `false`. There's a useless overhead! Meaning you should use `||` operator.

I don't think your constructor should be `protected`. After all, what's the use? You don't really want to do inheritance on a singleton class, it's just very weird. If you plan on using inheritance, consider adding an interface `IDBWorker` and implement the interface on different classes.

Your naming is a little off I think. `DBWorker` doesn't tell much except from the fact that it works with the Database. Its responsability is to store messages. So maybe `MessageRepository` (If you don't know the repository pattern, I recommend you read about it!) and `HostTest` is bad. Is it a test? I'd guess not. Ask yourself what is the responsability of your class and then you could name it easily! You can use [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866794/naming-classes-how-to-avoid-calling-everything-a-whatevermanager) to help you find good names!

Answer (score 3):

`SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, etc. all implement `IDisposable` and thus they should be encapsulated in `using` blocks. Instead you tie `SqlConnection` to a singleton class, which is the opposite of that.

[Here's how they should be used](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlconnection):

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Dogs1", con))
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",
            reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(2));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to create one connect when the service started. How can I use `using` in that case?

Comment: @MegaTron You shouldn't. Use a connection etc. when you need it and dispose of it as soon as possible. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/a/814606/648075 .

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of "magic if blocks":

```
if (instance == null)
    instance = new DBWorker();
```

Best practice is to always enclose if-then statements in braces:

```
if (instance == null)
{
    instance = new DBWorker();
}
```

That way if you ever need to add additional code (e.g. `instance.init()`), you'll be sure to have it in the right scope.

Another point is that your code isn't very testable; see [Make WCF Service testable](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33379/make-wcf-service-testable?rq=1) for some hints on that front.